# how to change the value of "xargs -I replace-str option"?

Tags: shell, xargs

I have a dir `log_test`,including some files,like:

```
flowMonitor.log.2017-06-26
flowMonitor.log.2017-06-27
gudong.log.17-06-23-16-54
gudong.log.17-06-23-19-11
...
```

Use the `find` command `find ./log_test -type f`,result is:

```
./log_test/flowMonitor.log.2017-06-26
./log_test/flowMonitor.log.2017-06-27
./log_test/gudong.log.17-06-23-16-54
./log_test/gudong.log.17-06-23-19-11
...
```

I want grep some keyword from these files,and store the result into a new file,but filename is related to the source file,like this:

```
grep "some keyword" ./log_test/flowMonitor.log.2017-06-26 > ./new_dir/flowMonitor.log.2017-06-26
```

**If I use the `xargs`，how to do？**

```
find ./log_test -type f | xargs -P 3 -n 1 ... grep "some keyword" ... > ...
```

Comment: **NOT Clear enough** and add `bash` tag

Comment: If you want to store those lines in your those files if they contain **some keyword** you can `perl -ne 'print if /some keyword/' *` and then redirect the **output** wherever you like